# How to perform an operation every time a node is viewed?

Tags: 7, hooks

When writing a module, how can I perform an operation every time a node is viewed by a user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) in Drupal 6 and check that the `$op` argument is 'view'. In Drupal 7, this has been changed to `hook_node_$op()` where `$op` is replaced by the value you would have checked for in the Drupal 6 version. So you would use [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7). For more details about the changes from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 see http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#remove_op.

Comment: This depends on whether the user is logged in and whether caching is turned on. The nodeapi hooks won't be called if caching is turned on and the user is anonymous or not logged in. You should clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could use Drupals Trigger module which has a 'When content is viewed by an authenticated user' trigger by default.

You can create an Action through /admin/settings/actions, or write your own based on the information at http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/trigger. You will also find modules that have predefined triggers and actions.

Comment: This (or the Rules module) is a good suggestion. However, the question mentions this in context of writing a module.

Comment: You are in fact right, however you can also define actions and triggers in code :)